# Return an anonymous instance/value in functions in C++

Tags: c++, anonymous-types, return-type

I have questions about the return type of function in C++.

Why `return pair<int, int>(1, 1);` and `return vector<int>(3, 3);` work? Shouldn't I create an local instance var before hand and take it as the return value, just like the return a, because `return int 1;` doesn't work.

```
// ...

int fun1() {
    // return int 1;
    int a = 1;
    return a;
}

pair<int, int> fun2() {
    return pair<int, int>(1, 1);
}

vector<int> fun3() {
    return vector<int>(3, 3);
}

int main(){
    cout << fun1() << endl;
    cout << fun2().first << endl;
    cout << fun3()[1] << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Is it such a style to return can only be applied on class instances with specific constructor? The example below can work. 
I'm looking for confirmation or reference materials.

```
class A {
public:
    int a;
    A(int a_) : a(a_) {};
};

A fun4() {
    return A(1);
}
```

Code sample tested in:

> Apple LLVM version 6.0 (clang-600.0.56) (based on LLVM 3.5svn) 
>   Target: x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0 
>   Thread model: posix

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> because `return int 1` doesn't work.

But `return int(1);` does... or `return 3 - 2;` for that matter.  There's nothing wrong with creating a temporary or using a literal - the class copy or move constructor will then be used if necessary to set the variable in the caller's context, or sometimes return Return Value Optimisation (RVO) will kick in and the called function will be able to create the return value directly in the caller's stack.

Comment: I think bringing move constructors and RVO into it is just liable to cause confusion and not clarify anything.

Comment: @JonathanWakely: countering that, there are myriad questions on SO where people put `std::cout << "copying\n";` in their copy constructor and wonder why it's not used when returning by value... bit of a "damned if you do, damned if you don't" situation IMHO.